# Segmentation fault when using if statement with pointers (BST tree)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a binary search tree in C, more specifically looking for the predecessor. However, whenever I try to run the program I get the segmentation vault. Here's the code in question:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tree
{
    int a;
    tree *left;
    tree *right;
    tree *prev;
}*root=NULL;

tree *searchSpecific (tree *root, int val)
{
    tree *x=root;
    if (!x)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(x && val!=x->a)
        {
            if (val>x->a)
                x=x->left;
            else x=x->right;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

int previous(tree *root, int f)
{
 tree *x=searchSpecific(root,f);
    if(x->left)
    {
        x=x->left;
        while(x->right) x = x->right;
        return x->a;
    }

    tree *temp;
    do
    {
        temp = x;
        x = x->prev;
    } while(x && (x->right != temp));
    return x->a;
}
```

The segfault appears at the if statement if(x->left) in the previous() function. I want to check if the node in question exists, but the program crashes every time and I have no idea what is wrong with it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `searchSpecific` may return `NULL`, you need to protect your code from it, and check `x` before accessing one of its members:

```
tree *x=searchSpecific(root,f);
if (x != NULL && x->left)
```

Comment: Not sufficient:  the crash moves down but bites again: `do { temp = x;  x = x->prev; ...`.  Another illustration of how `do / while` loops are mostly broken.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end I've added the 'x != NULL' into the first 'if()' and put the 'do...while' loop into an 'if(x)' statement and it fixed all the issued.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault can appear due to several reasons, such as:

- x is undefined, which may be caused by your *searchSpecific function
- x is NULL, because your function returns a NULL pointer
- x->left is NULL, which means trying to access it causes something bad to happen

So, how I'll go about doing this would be trying to check if the returned tree is null using a simple if statement as follows:

```
if (x == NULL) {
    /* throw error or not found message */
}
```

I would also suggest you dynamically allocate memory for your tree before doing anything with it, by creating a reusable func like create_tree() with the following code:

```
tree create_tree(int data) {
    tree *x;
    x = malloc(sizeof(tree));
    x->a = data;
    x->left = x->right = x->prev = NULL;
    return x;
}
```

Why? Note that in your code snippets, you just declare

```
 tree *some_tree_name;
```

which is very dangerous every time you try to do something with it, and might lead to your code crashing on you on the do/while loop later.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. Like I said in the other comment I've added an 'if(x)' statement around the 'do...while' loop and the 'x != NULL' into the already existing 'if(()'. I'll make sure to remember about the dynamic allocation :).